# How doesn't overloading operator() override class constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

Having the following class with the `operator()(string)` function and the constructor `X(string)`:

```
class X
{
public:
    string n;

    X(string s) : n(s) {}

    void operator() (string s)
    {
        cout << "func";
    }
};
```

Why doesn't `X x("a"),y("b");` raise any errors? How does the compiler knows which function to choose?

Comment: `X` only has one constructor  so there is no choice needed

Comment: There is no ambiguity. `X x("a")` couldn't possibly call `operator()`. What would `x`'s `n` be? If you wanted to call `operator()` on a temporary `X` you could use something like `X ("a")("b");`

Comment: So there is nothing ambiguous? The operator function takes the same argument as the class' constructor. @FrançoisAndrieux why is that impossible?

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu You need an instance of `X` to call `operator()`.

Comment: @Peter my `operator()` returns `void` not `string`

Answer (score 0):

```
X x("a"),y("b");
```

Is equivalent with

```
X x("a");
X y("b");
```

So I will focus on

```
X x("a");
```

This is a declaration and initialization of the variable `x`. Only constructors and conversions (*) are considered.

`operator()` is the function call operator. It is used to call on a object as if it were a function. So it is used on an existing object. E.g.:

```
X x("asd"); // <-- constructor call
x("yolo"); // <-- operator() call
```

---

As a side note I recommend using the brace init syntax `{}` to initialize objects:

```
X x{"asd"};
auto x = X{"asd"};
```

---

*) *As a bonus*, here is an example of an user defined conversion operator used:

```
struct X { };

struct Y
{
    operator X() const { return X{}; }
};

auto test()
{
    Y y;

    X x(y);
    // the above line is equivalent with:
    X x = static_cast<X>(y.operator X());
}
```

I used `X x(y)` to mimic your example, but again, I recommend:

```
auto test()
{
    Y y{};
    X x{y};
}
```

instead